# How to print the results of Elasticsearch aggregation as a JSON string in Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using the Java client to query the Elasticsearch cluster. On querying, I get the result as a `SearchResponse`. From it, I get the aggregations as `Aggregations agg = sr.getAggregations();`. How do I print out the full result as JSON like the result which is got from cURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to print the SearchResponse object, for example:

```
SearchResponse response = search.execute().actionGet();
log.debug("Response: {}", response);
```

you can do the same with SearchRequestBuilder:

```
SearchRequestBuilder search = client.prepareSearch(INDEX)...
log.debug("Search: {}", search);
```